How to quit mosh? How to type: Ctrl-^ (caret)
I've never managed to actually quit mosh successfully using the suggested command: [To quit: Ctrl-^ .]
How do I enter this? Which physical keys do I need to press on the keyboard? I'm on MacOS but the problem is probably independent of OS.
To make it easier to Google this issue, here are alternative ways to describe the character sequence:

Control/Ctrl + Caret/Circumflex/Hat


After much experimentation, I figured out that the solution is to:

Simultaneously hold down and then release: Ctrl+6
Followed by .

The trick is that one must not hold down Shift. Just pressing the 6 key is enough. I don't know why mosh doesn't just say that.
If the above doesn't work, try these similar questions:

How to quit Mosh inside Tmux inside Mosh
How to type Ctrl-^?

